# Multiple instances of PowerPoint (2007)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

How can I open PowerPoint twice so I can view two presentations, one on each screen of my dual monitor set up?

Comment: note to self - just upgraded to Office 2010 - and i can open two versions of powerpoint :)

Comment: Broken again in 2013. -- At least it doesn't work the way other apps do, like Excel where you can just click the icon again.  Opening a new presentation from the file menu works; or right clicking the icon with run-as Administrator seems to work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As M'vy [points out](https://superuser.com/a/301670/155449), it's not really possible right now without running the other copy in a separate user space (i.e. by using `RunAs`).  Aside from running it twice, perhaps you could stretch it across both monitors and then open both presentations.

From the [PPTFaq site](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00793.htm):

> - If PowerPoint is maximized, click the "Restore Down" button (the one to the left of the "Make it Go Away" X in the upper right hand corner).
> - Drag the lower right hand corner to the right to expand the PPT screen onto the second monitor.
> - Open two presentations
> - Choose Window, Arrange All from the main menu bar.

Comment: its a shame it does not seem possible. thanks for a work around

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go ahead and post this as an answer because it took me about 20 minutes to figure it out.   Really, this is just a work-around but nothing else I found worked or wasn't practical for my situation (like creating a second user).

**Save your Power Point as a PDF.**  Open up multiple instances of your PDF viewer (Adobe, browser, whatever).

Answer (score 2):

Note that two PowerPoint items in the taskbar is not the same as two instances of PowerPoint.

If you look at your task list/processes, you'll only see one instance of Powerpnt.exe, and you'll also find that you can't work in multiple independent PPT windows, each with its own ribbon or toolbar/menu UI.

For that, as has been pointed out, you need to resort to multiple user tricks or bump to PPT 2010.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that running two copies of MS Office 2007 is not possible so far.

The only workaround I know is to run office with as another user, but it has some inconveniences.

Answer (score 0):

Actually click on the PPT files, don't just click the shortcut to open Office 2007 in the start menu. I just did this and attached a screen shot of my task bar. You can see the two instances to the right. I do not have dual monitors to show the whole application open.

As a note, in Office 2010, it will actually open a new instance of PowerPoint even from the Start menu. I also tested this as I use 2010 primarily.

[image]

Comment: @slhck How do you send those comments that go directly to a user? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the [@-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)? Or are you talking about another specific case?

Comment: @slhck Your reply to me about the edit went only to my responses, not here. Is there a way to send certain comments only to the user?

Comment: @KCotreau I'm sorry, I don't really understand -- Which "reply about the edit" are you referring to? What did not go "here"? What is "here"? I am afraid I only know of the @-replies and for as long as I've been here, I've always got my responses both in the inbox (top left) as well as in the responses in the profile.

Comment: When you edited my image, in my responses, I got this message: "removed large white space in the image", but it did not appear in this list of comments. I am wondering how that response even got to me, and even independent of these "Add comments", can you send a message directly to another user?

Comment: @KCotreau if you look at this post's [revision history](http://superuser.com/posts/301675/revisions) you can see this is simply the message that slhck entered for the edit summary when performing the edit. The system notifies you when posts that you own are edited, but slhck didn't do anything specific to make this happen.

Comment: I never noticed that edit summary...that is how. Thanks.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Apart from that, there's no way of contacting people other than through Chat or @-replies.

Answer (score 0):

Open power point and when you have 2 monitors....   select Slide show tab... then on the far right of the menu select ... show presentation on- (what monitor you choose) then open the other power point and it will open on the other monitor and set the first power point in slide show and scroll up and down in it so you can compare the 2 power points and edit the 2nd power point off the first power point's info...  it is a trick when you want to keep a copy of a PPT and update / make another one with the info without bouncing back and forth off the task bar...

Works for Office 2007....

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerPoint 2013:
1. open instance of PP 2013, to get 1st window.
2. click and drag 1st .pptx file onto it.
3. right-click task bar PPT icon and select PPT 2013, to open a 2nd window.
4.  click and drag 2nd .pptx file onto 2nd window.

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could show two presentations in PPT 2007 at once by opening two files in PPT, then using View | Arrange All and then starting the slide show on each.  They of course must be set to run in a window, not Full Screen.  It does not matter if I have one monitor or two.  The only restriction is that the presentations must all run within the "big" window.  For example, you can't have a PDF visible in between the two PPT presentations, but you can of course re-arrange and re-size the shows within the "big" PPT window.  Jerry

Comment: This solution is great EXCEPT if you have Use Timings set, it will only advance the presentation that has focus.  You can't have two presentations running and automatically advancing; only one at a time can have focus.  Jerry

Answer (score -1):

From the Windows 7 task bar:

- right click the PowerPoint 2007 icon to open the jump list
- select 'Microsoft PowerPoint 2007'

This should launch another instance of PowerPoint 2007 (this can be used to launch another instance of almost all applications).  I used this frequently before upgrading to Office 2010 with Excel 20007.

Comment: This doesn't work with PowerPoint 2007.

Comment: Thats too bad, it'd be nice if that feature worked across the board.  Guess its another reason to upgrade!

Answer (score -1):

i was able to get multiple instances of ppt running by doing the following

1. i had multiple slides opened at the same time then i "arranged all" from the view menu in the toolbar.
2. after doing this, every other slide that i opened would do so in a seperate instance of ppt.

using ppt from office 12 by the way.

Comment: The question is about Office 2007. Your answer unfortunately doesn't work.